# How to view mu4e - emacs buffer in browser?

Tags: emacs

In mutt I have been able to set up things so that for text/html mail a "v" will call up a selection list and I can then having set up my  mailcap file I can pipe the message to firefox (or other web browser for viewing). This is sometimes useful for messages where mutt seems to have trouble finding the urls.

This same problem happens when using mu4e in emacs. For some mailings the links will not show up (though using w3m to render) the links, and I can't figure out how to pipe the message buffer to some external program for rendering and clicking to follow links.

Thank you.
Using mu4e from github version 9.11C and emacs 24.4.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add this to your configuration:

```
(add-to-list 'mu4e-view-actions '("ViewInBrowser" . mu4e-action-view-in-browser) t)
```

Then, `a V` opens the current message in the default web browsers.

More information in the documentation: [(mu4e) Reading messages](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Reading-messages.html).

Comment: This assumes you did `(add-to-list 'mu4e-view-actions '("ViewInBrowser" . mu4e-action-view-in-browser) t)` as suggested in the documentation (`(info "(mu4e) Reading messages")`).

Comment: Thanks @YoungFrog, I missed to mention that.

Comment: Thanks both, I've incorporated this in the answer.